# Trying to get property of non-object in action column in yii2

Tags: yii2

I've customized the query in FrameSearch Model and build my query with findbysql. I'm also trying to customize the action column. My gridview looks fine except the action Column.
Getting error - 
[image]

FrameSearch Model Code -

```
<?php

namespace frontend\modules\framestock\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use frontend\modules\framestock\models\Frame;
use frontend\modules\framestock\models\Poitemframe;
use yii\db\Query;
use yii\db\Command;
/**
 * FrameSearch represents the model behind the search form about `frontend\modules\framestock\models\Frame`.
 */
class FrameSearch extends Frame
{
    public $purchase;
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['f_id'], 'integer'],
            [['f_brand', 'f_name','purchase'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function scenarios()
    {
        // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
        return Model::scenarios();
    }

    /**
     * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
     *
     * @param array $params
     *
     * @return ActiveDataProvider
     */
    public function search($params)
    {
        $subQuery1 = (new Query())->select(['poi_framename','sum(poi_qty) as purchased'])->from ('poitemframe')->join('LEFT JOIN','Frame','frame.f_name = poitemframe.poi_framename')->groupby('poi_framename');        
        $subQuery2 = (new Query())->select(['o_frame','count(o_frame) as sold'])->from ('orders')->join('LEFT JOIN','Frame','frame.f_name = orders.o_frame')->groupby('o_frame');        
        $query = (new Query())->select(['f_brand','f_name','COALESCE(pt.purchased,0)as purchased' , 'COALESCE(st.sold,0) as sold', '(COALESCE(pt.purchased,0) - COALESCE(st.sold,0)) as stock'])->from ('frame')->leftJoin(['pt' => $subQuery1],'pt.poi_framename = frame.f_name')->leftJoin(['st' => $subQuery2],'st.o_frame = frame.f_name');


        // ->joinWith(['purchase']);
        // $items = $query
        //         ->select([
        //             'f_brand',
        //             'f_name',
        //             'sum(poitemframe.poi_qty) as purchased',
        //             ])
        //         //->where(['stock.product_id'=>3])
        //         ->groupBy('f_name')
        //         ->all();



        // add conditions that should always apply here

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        // grid filtering conditions
        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'f_id' => $this->f_id,
        ]);

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'f_brand', $this->f_brand])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'f_name', $this->f_name]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

index.php

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\grid\GridView;
use yii\db\Query;
use yii\db\Command;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel frontend\modules\framestock\models\FrameSearch */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = 'Frames';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="frame-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
    <?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>

    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            'f_brand',
            'f_name',
            'purchased',
            'sold',
            'stock',

            [
            'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
            'template' => '{ledger}',
            'buttons' => [
                'ledger' => function ($url, $model) {
                    return Html::a(
                        '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>',
                        ['/frame/ledger', 'f_name' => $model->f_name], 
                        [
                            'title' => 'Ledger',
                            'data-pjax' => '0',
                        ]
                    );
                },
            ],
            ],
        ],
    ]); ?>
</div>
```

**update**

[image]

After adding exit;
[image]

Please tell me how to resolve this. I want to get the f_name from the action column button which I'll pass to another page to filter a grid.

Comment: use `var_dump($model);` and inspect content.

Comment: after which line?

Comment: inside ` 'ledger' => function ($url, $model) {}`

Comment: it's completely ignoring this line. I've added in the question. Please have a look.

Comment: try to use: $model['f_name']

Comment: add **exit** after that.

Comment: @InsaneSkull I've added the output in the question. Please have a look.

Comment: try with `$model['f_name']` or `$model->f_name`, one should work.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks InsaneSkull and Yasin.

Comment: That's how you should debug code for simple problems like this.

Comment: Many many thanks for this lesson.

Comment: I think that you have `asArray()` call somewhere in the query definition. Most probably in the controller

Answer (score 0):

I usually recommend to use [ArrayHelper::getValue](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basearrayhelper.html#getValue()-detail) .

For example:

```php
ArrayHelper::getValue($model, 'f_name')
```

will work when `$model` is some object (`Model` or `ActiveRecord`), array or empty (`=null`).
Moreover, it has 3nd argument for default value:

```php
ArrayHelper::getValue($model, 'f_name', 'value that returned when attribute not found in $model')
```